# Dynamically generating friendly URL and render the content from SQL db in unique page for all posts clicked in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting, repeater

As I am constructing a blog section in my website I would like to know how to render each of the blog post in unique page template or say view. I do not want to create aspx manually and then naming them with headings SEO.

Step 1 : I have created a table where it can totally store all the details, including image, content, heading and I am able to retrieve these values to bind it further in the repeater. Working fine

Step 2: However, Now next thing is,there is blog details page which will be displayed when clicked on any of the blogs, but will it bear the different URL as to match with the heading ?

Assume currently URL is www.xyz.com/blog/blogdeatils.aspx and if it is rendering a article which talks about wikipedia then I want my URL to be www.xyz.com/blog/how-wikipedia-works (no aspx extension)

Is this possible ? Thank you all

Comment: Reference to `.aspx` indicates Web Forms (rather than MVC). You can use routing in Web Forms to direct multiple URLs to the same page.

Comment: any links for the same ? I have already added some code in global file where i am able to get the pages to contact from contact.aspx but how to do dynamic url generating ? is that possible ? how to reference each and every blog post to same page ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been called as "routing". Add *Global.asax* to your project and next is just an example of your file:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>


<script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Article", "blog/{name}", "~/BlogDetails.aspx");
}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown

}

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started

}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

}
```

And in your *BlogDetails.aspx* you may use next code to fetch the title of the article:

```
string article_name = Page.RouteData.Values["name"] == null ? "No article" : Page.RouteData.Values["name"].ToString();
```

And then use this for retrieving information from a database.

Comment: Thank you for the time and answer, though code is slightly self explanatory i wish to know if above code helps me in say for example i have inserted 5 articles in my db with image, headline, content..now when i retrieve them via repeater i can see all of them in single page but my worry is if someone clicks on particular blog then they should be forwarded to blogdetails.aspx but url should be showing up differently as per the headline stored in db. what i understood in ur code is that we are referncing blogdetails.aspx but please fill the gap and clear my doubts, big thanks

Comment: @santhoshkumarB as you could see, you have a route like *blog/{name}* with redirecting to the *blogdetails.aspx*. It means that *blog/how-to-clean-a-car*, *blog/how-to-clean-a-home*, *blog/how-to-wash-a-dish* and so on will be redirected to the *blogdetails.aspx*, but in address field you will see like *xyz.com/blog/how-to-clean-a-car*. In *blogdetails.aspx* you will get a route value and work with it. Example: *RetrieveDetailsByArticleName(Page.RouteData.Values["name"])*. Hope you understand this

Comment: I was waiting for your reply, meanwhile was doing some research on this. if someone is visiting my website for  blog/how-to-clean-a-home ,  do you mean to say that i will be able to understand dis in blogdetails.aspx code behind file with the method (Page.RouteData.Values["name"]) ? just like you check sessions ? so once i get the values to a string, next what ?

Comment: @santhoshkumar then you will do something like following: *SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr); SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select image, addeddate, info from myTable where lower(name) = lower(@name)", con); cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Page.RouteData.Values["name"].ToString();*. Hope you get the ide

Comment: Good noon Brother, Yes I have done something like this, i am taking value as querystring and passing value in page load itself, which will do exactly the process you wrote above but URL looks ugly as you know ww.xyz.com/blogdetail.aspx?Id=4 ...is there way for me to retain this technique but also modify the URL with that of heading ? second question is, if I have to use Page.ReoutedData instead of querystring then I will have to assign particular value to anchor tag? that makes it easier to match id rather than whole name itself ? in this process should we manually add names in global.ascx

Comment: @santhoshkumarB I will upload one more detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

Your *Global.ascx* file's content:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>


<script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Article", "blog/{name}", "~/BlogDetails.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("Main Page", "Home", "~/Default.aspx");
}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown
}

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
}
```

Consume that you have some table *Articles*, which contains such columns as *ID, Name, Image, Info*. And you have *Image* control for an image and *Label* control for a detail information in your *BindDetails.aspx*. So your *BindDetails.aspx.cs* will be (excepting namespaces):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (Page.RouteData.Values["name"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/Home");
    else{
        string name = Page.RouteData.Values["name"].ToString();
        if (!IsPostBack)
            RetrieveArticleByItsName(name);
    }
}

protected void RetrieveArticleByItsName(string article){
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select TOP 1 * from Articles where lower(name) = lower(@name)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = article;

    try{
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        sdr.Read();
        imgImage.ImageUrl = "your_folder/" + sdr["image"].ToString();
        lblDetails.Text = sdr["info"].ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //work with exceptions
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');</script"); // Get alert with exception
    }
    finally{
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

And let's think, that you have two articles with names "*How-to-clean-home*" and "*How-to-clean-a-car*". Now you may give everybody links like *xyz.com/blog/How-to-clean-home* and *xyz.com/blog/How-to-clean-a-car* and it will work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: fantastic Bro, Thank you for your explanation, Just one more doubt here, should we not assign name value to the anchor tag ? currently my anchor tag looks like this <a href="blogdetail.aspx?Id = <%#Eval("Id")%>"><%#Eval("Heading")%></a>, this is helping me in page load like this int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["Id"], out Id); ..Now what should i replace my Eval ID with if I have to implement your solution ? how can i assign the value at first ? highly admiring your contribution to this

Comment: *<a href='<%#String.Format("blog/{0}", Eval("NAME"))%>'><%#Eval("NAME") %></a>* Replace *NAME* with the article name column

Comment: It will be something like *<a href='blog/How-to-clean-a-computer'>How-to-clean-a-computer</a>*

Comment: yes, trying that but however do you suggest stuffing the line from How To clean a car = How-to-clean-a-car with hyphens ? and next question is am unable to extract values, am trying to extract it like this             string article_ = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Heading"]);
or should i be employing this         string name = Page.RouteData.Values["name"].ToString();
?

Comment: I had the second problem solved by using the Page.RouteData.Values["name"].ToString(); am able to extract values now, Do you suggest stuffing on run time or better to seperately store the stuffed headline to compare and authenticate ? which is better

Comment: @santhoshkumarB I recommend you to add one more field for url, and store duplicate of Heading with hyppens, like "How-to", not "How to"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104849/discussion-between-santhoshkumar-b-and-khazratbek).